# refactoring a field into a property

Tags: vb.net, properties, encapsulation

I am currently learning vb.net for my new job and I have mixed feelings over public fields. I see many arguments about them hurting the encapsulation. In python, the common practice is to keep things simple and use fields when they are enough. If we want to add logic later, we just refactor them into a property without breaking anything for the client code.

In the codebase I am working with I see huge classes containing dozen of properties like:

```
Private __GetDescriptionMode As Boolean
<DefaultValue(False)> _
 Public Property GetDescriptionMode() As Boolean
    Get
        GetDescriptionMode = __GetDescriptionMode
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Boolean)
        __GetDescriptionMode = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

That's 10 lines of code with little value inside. I can barely see 3 of them in my visual studio window. So I have 2 questions:

- Is there a valid reason not to simply define fields and refactor them into properties when needed?
- Are OOP principle so important to sacrifice so much readability? (I can look at fewer things, I have to parse the property to make sure they are'nt doing anything special, etc)

**EDIT**
To clarify my first question: Do I have a chance of breaking client code if I change a field into a trivial property?

Comment: If it's about readability, you can simply collapse your properties so you have 1 line props.

Comment: but then I don't know if they contain any logic. Readability means that I can look to the code. Otherwise I can just look at the class browser

Comment: For the props who have logic, you could put a line of comment above the prop indicating it contains logic.

Comment: I can't see using comments as a flag for properties containing logic as a sustainable solution.

Comment: For non-logic containing fields, you can just use auto-implementation.

Comment: Is looking at the properties really that cumbersome? I've never heard a programmer say that before. You want to write the best code and typically that favors properties over public fields. If viewing a few extra lines of code is that awful, you maaaaaay be in the wrong field (no pun intended).

Comment: @Yatrix programming is about communication. If you can put the same information in ten time less lines, it is definitely a huge gain. We read code more often than we write some. So the less the better. Ever heard of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)?

Comment: @Simon I doubt DRY says program the wrong way because you don't want to read more code. Programming is about doing a task and it should be done the RIGHT way. Doing it the wrong way because you don't want to read it (seriously?) "communicates" that you are either lazy or don't care about doing a good job. Regardless, that's not "communication" your teammates want to be a part of. No one likes mopping up after someone else's junk code, so just write it the correct way, even if that takes you a whole extra 3 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a good idea to create properties rather than fields.

- You can break client code if you change a public field into a public property.
- You can only use data-binding with properties.
- Fields can't be used in interfaces
- You will break binary serialization code if you change a public field into a public property.
- If you are using reflection, changing a field to a property later could break your reflection code.

Read more from this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2009/09/04/properties-vs-fields-why-does-it-matter-jonathan-aneja.aspx) by the Vb.Net team, or this from [Jon Skeet](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx) about the same issue in C#

In Visual Basic 2010 and later, use auto-properties

```
Public Property GetDescriptionMode As Boolean
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO its always worth setting up the properties in the first place:

- You may well be making someone else's life harder when they need the properties.
- May also mean unnecessary amendments to projects with many dependencies.
- If you don't like space taken up by the properties, wrap then in a `Region`
- Various things such as reflection/data binding etc may have issues with fields.

Worth saying that, as of VS2010, this problem largely goes away with the advent of auto-properties. The above would condense to:

```
Public Property GetDescriptionMode As Boolean
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you give exemples for the first two points? For the third point I would rather be able to read the code. For the last point, it could be a problem when switching from a property to a field. Not the other way...

Comment: 1: When you're writing code to be used in enterprise you're writing code to be consumed by other people. If you've taken the lazy way and written fields, someone else will have to convert them to properties later. Better to take the few seconds it takes to write the property in the first place.

Comment: 2: Suppose you've written a class using Fields, and that class is used in a host of other libraries,sites,apps etc, which pass instances of the class around. Then someone needs the properties. You end up having to make unnecessary changes to the dependency, and then having to revisit the other projects to include the change.

Comment: I don't value fields because they are easier to write. I value them because they are easier to read. I don't mind typing boiler plate code for a trivial property. I simply mind having a class containing ten times the number of code lines it should.

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at is that, when you write code, its not good to take the easy way out at the point of writing. You should try to write code that is as reusable as possible, even if that takes you a little longer, in the overall scheme, it'll save time and effort.